# Automatically deploy container registry images to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I was setting up CI/CD for my Spring Boot project, and am able to have image created in container registry whenever a push happens. How can I deploy this image automatically to Cloud Run then? I tried adding a step to the cloudbuild.yaml file like this -

```
name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
args:
- 'run'
- 'deploy'
- 'cloudrunservice'
- '--image=gcr.io/sample1-319510/sample1image'
- '--region='asia-south1'
- '--platform=managed'
- '--allow-unauthenticated'
```

But, this didn't work, and I got error about 'cloudrunservice' not being there.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build

Comment: Paste the full error description

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of your Cloud Run service = "cloudrunservice"?
In order to deploy Cloud Run in one of Cloud Build stages, you can do like this:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'SERVICE-NAME', '--image', 'gcr.io/sample1-319510/sample1image', '--region', 'asia-south1', '--platform', 'managed', '--allow-unauthenticated']
```

Just replace SERVICE-NAME with the name of your cloud run service.
Document for reference: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run